# Can I Add Custom Formatting Markup to MediaWiki?

Tags: css, formatting, mediawiki, markup

Is it possible to add custom formatting markup to MediaWiki?

Say, for example, I have a div style I use quite often and I'd like to make markup to apply it more quickly than using <div id="frequentlyusedstyle">Title</div> -- like surrounding the text with @@Title@@ instead of typing out the div id. Is that possible?

(I realize that there is already heading markup; that's just an example. Thank you in advance!)

Comment: you want templates: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#CSS_and_JavaScript_code

Comment: Nah, I was hoping for some shorthand I could use _in_ templates.

Comment: I'm also interested to do this. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new page named "Template:name", where 'name' is whatever you want to name it, with the following text (as per your example):

< div id="frequentlyusedstyle">{{{1|}}}< /div>

(minus the extra spaces, since I don't know how to keep html from
parsing here.)

You would then use it by adding {{template name|Title}} to an article, and it will invoke the style.

You will need to have a style defined in MediaWiki:Common.css or similar, in order to style that div, such as:

```
#frequentlyusedstyle {
    color: red;
}
```

Hope that helps.